# How does a morphism in a distinguished triangle induce an element of $\operatorname{Ext}^{2}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, sheaf-cohomology, triangulated-categories

On p. 260 of Deligne and Illusie's paper (https://eudml.org/doc/143480) it says:

> Let $e(K)\in\operatorname{Ext}^{2}(H^{1}(K),H^{0}(K))$ be the class defined by the degree $1$ morphism in the distinguished triangle
> $$H^{0}(K)\longrightarrow K\longrightarrow H^{1}K[-1]\longrightarrow^{+1}$$

What is meant by "the class defined by the degree 1 morphism"? How does a degree-1 morphism in a distinguished triangle define an element of $\operatorname{Ext}^{2}$? Sorry if that question is stupid, I am only a beginner when it comes to triangulated categories. Can someone please explain it to me in as much detail as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A morphism of degree 1 from $A$ to $B$ is by definition the same as a morphism $A \to B[1]$. In your case, this is an element in
$$
\mathrm{Hom}(H^1(K)[-1],H^0(K)[1]) \cong
\mathrm{Hom}(H^1(K),H^0(K)[2]) \cong
\mathrm{Ext}^2(H^1(K),H^0(K)).
$$

Comment: Why is $Hom(H^{1}(K),H^{0}(K)[2])\cong Ext^{2}(H^{1}(K),H^{0}(K))$? Sorry if that question is stupid.

Comment: It is better to read this standard fact in a textbook.